# FlaUI | Unable to find DevExpress control Combobox

Tags: winforms, devexpress, ui-automation, devexpress-windows-ui, flaui

We are using DevExpress controls 18.2v. Unable to extract devexpress combo boxes edit using FlaUI to implement automation testing.

I tried multiple ways (Xpath, process id, etc.,  and no luck.) using the code below, unable to get a reference to the combo box; the below statement returned null.

```
using (var app = FlaUI.Core.Application.Launch(@"MYAPP.EXE")) 
    {
        try
        {
            using (var automation = new UIA3Automation())
            {
                var mainWindow = app.GetMainWindow(automation);
                
                ConditionFactory cf = new ConditionFactory(new UIA3PropertyLibrary());
                
                var searchOptionSelection = mainWindow.FindFirstDescendant(cf.ByAutomationId("cmbSearch")); //?.Select(1);
                
                var searchOptionSelection11 = mainWindow.FindFirstDescendant(cf.ByClassName("WindowsForms10.Window.b.app.0.134c08f_r6_ad1"));
               
                var searchOptionSelection1 = mainWindow.FindFirstByXPath(@"/Window[3]/Pane[4]/Window[1]/Pane/Pane[1]/Pane/Pane/Tab/Pane/Pane/ComboBox"); //?.Select(1);
                
                searchOptionSelection1 = mainWindow.FindFirstByXPath("//ComboBox[@AutomationId=cmbSearch]");
                
                var cmbSearchButton = mainWindow.FindFirstDescendant(cf.ByName("Open")).AsButton(); //ComboBox edit button
                
                var searchOptionSelection2 = mainWindow.FindAll(FlaUI.Core.Definitions.TreeScope.Descendants, cf.ByAutomationId("cmbSearch"));
                
        }
        finally
        {
            //dispose objects
        }
    }
```

[Autommation id screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkvHm.png)

Any help is much appreciated!

I figured out the solution. My app has multiple top windows, and they are not children of one another. So that caused FlaUI to return NULL.

Searching using a desktop, identified combo control and returned the reference...

```
AutomationElement desktop = automation.GetDesktop();
var comboxItem = desktop.FindFirstDescendant(cf.ByAutomationId("cmbSearch"))?.AsComboBox();
var comboxItemButton = desktop.FindFirstDescendant(cf.ByName("Open"))?.AsButton();
comboxItemButton.Click(true);
comboxItem.Select(1); // This is NOT working now.
```

Any idea on the last statement to make it work?

Comment: I figured out the solution. My app has multiple top windows, and they are not children of one another. So that caused FlaUI to return NULL. 

Below code worked once I searched using a desktop..
    AutomationElement desktop = automation.GetDesktop();
    var comboxItem = desktop.FindFirstDescendant(cf.ByAutomationId("cmbSearch"))?.AsComboBox();
    var comboxItemButton = desktop.FindFirstDescendant(cf.ByName("Open"))?.AsButton();
    comboxItemButton.Click(true);
    comboxItem.Select(1); // This is NOT working now. 

Any idea on the last statement to make it work?